# How can I use classes of osgi fragment in host bundle?

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle

Suppose I have one osgi plugin and then I have created one osgi fragment by keeping that plugin as host.

Now I want to use code of osgi fragment in my osgi plugin.

Please help me as I am new in osgi.

---

Comment: Why do you want to use fragments ? Please add some details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need fragment because I want to keep some code separate from my plugin.

Comment: Yes - it's precisely the objective of OSGi, decoupled services and isolation. You don't need fragment to achieve this, especially if you are new to osgi: a fragment is an advanced concept, mostly here to help with legacy libraries or some special use case.

Comment: So how can I achieve this ? And If I can achieve it by fragment cant it create cyclic dependency ?

Comment: As @JérémieB said: you don't need to use a fragment. It would be irresponsible for us to tell you how to hurt yourself.

Comment: Neil & Jeremy know what they're talking about. Follow some OSGi tutorial, like http://enroute.osgi.org/book/150-tutorials.html to get a basic understanding how to decompose an application in OSGi

Answer (score 0):

Its a hack, but it will get you what you ask for - make sure that host bundle contains following header `Bundle-ClassPath: /patch,.`. It contradicts framework behavior and expectation by prioritizing "patch" path above host classpath.
This means that, once you place compiled classes under "patch", they will override existing classes from fragment host itself.

You probably should use a different way to solve that problem.